# Broadcast Message in Android through Wi-Fi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have a requirement to send a broadcast message from one android device to N different android devices under the reach. Note that all devices have Wi-Fi on including the first one, but first one is not creating any Hotspot and other are not joining, all devices including the first one simply switch on the Wi-Fi that's it. So my question is, can i send a broadcast message to all those N devices and is there any API to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using multicast UDP packets, but it will only work when phone is awake.

You can also grab wakelock on phones that are listening but it will drain your battery very fast.

Check out this link:
https://gist.github.com/finnjohnsen/3654994

Comment: Doesn't it require to create a hotspot and then join it?

Comment: No. It should work in local network - devices must be in the same network.

Comment: Means i have to create a Local Network before using it?